# Error with python 'NameError: name '' is not defined' python 2.7.12

Tags: python

Using python 2.7.12 im using a simple program:

```
import time
print('Whats Your Name?')
name=input()
print('Happy Birthday to You')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Happy Birthday to You')
time.sleep(1.8)
print('Happy Birthday Dear '+name)
time.sleep(2)
print('Happy Birthday to You')
time.sleep(1.5)
```

however when i try to input name i get this:

Whats Your Name?
Jeff

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\happybirthday.py", line 3, in <module>
    name=input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Jeff' is not defined
```

Why? This seems to happen on every program which requires an input.

Comment: Since you're a newcomer, I warmly recommend that you ditch Python 2 **now** and switch to Python 3.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input()` as opposed to `input()` as you are using Python 2.x.

In Python 2.x `input()` will will try and evaluate your input whereas `raw_input()` will return a string which you can use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) to [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) which returns a string.

On Python `2.x` [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) tries to evaluate its input, while [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string. On Python 3 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) replaces [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a string into `name` from what the user types, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between `raw_input()` and `input()`:

#### In Python2.x:

**`input()` is looking for an expression.**

if you give `1+1` to `input()`, it will evaluate it and return `2`.
`jeff` being not an expression, it will throw an error.
if input is `"jeff"` or `'jeff'`, `input()` will return the same string.

**`raw_input()` is looking for a string.**

if you give `1+1` to `raw_input()`, it will return `"1+1"`(string).
if you give `jeff` to `raw_input()`, it will return `"jeff"`.

#### In Python3.x:

`raw_input()` is renamed as `input()` and `raw_input()` is removed.